# Sort of static inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I've seen loads of answers saying this doesn't exists, for various reasons - and lots of them make sense.

For my use case however, i feel that what i'm doing does make sense, and so logically there should be a way to do it...

I want to have a series of static classes, each with 3 methods. The first method of each is unique to each of the classes, but the second two methods are just transformations of the first method; i.e.

```
public static class A{
  public static double[][] x(...){...}
  public static double[][] y(...){//calls x in here and operates on output}
  public static double[][] z(...){//also calls x in here and operates on output}
}
public static class B{
  public static double[][] x(...){...} //different
  public static double[][] y(...){} //identical to A.y, but calls B.x inside.
  public static double[][] z(...){} //identical to A.Z, but calls B.x inside.
}
public static class C{
  public static double[][] x(...){...}
  public static double[][] y(...){} //identical to A.y, but calls C.x inside.
  public static double[][] z(...){} //identical to A.Z, but calls C.x inside.
}
```

I would much rather have a way that i define the static functions `y` and `z`, and then only have to define `x` for each of the classes i'll actually use.

The classes are essentially just containers for different methods, which are essentially the same, but with different underlying functions.

Is there a way to do this without lots of boilerplate?

Comment: How about making this class non-static and using a Singleton pattern?

Comment: "so logically there should be a way to do it..." - No, that's a false assumption. Just because it makes sense it is not necessarily possible. I think what you're after is the singleton pattern.

Comment: Write a method which accept delegate (to call `x()`) and call this method from `A.y`, `B.y` and `C.y` with different delegate. E.g. `B.y()` will call it with `B.x`.

Comment: *"I want to have a series of static classes, each with 3 methods."* => Why do these methods and classes need to be `static`? "I want" is not a technical requirement.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. It depends on the case. Show the practical example. How are you going to use these static classes?

Comment: I don't understand how those classes are even related in the example?

Comment: @Jon the reason i *want* it is because it's essentially a library of lots of functions. I want to divide all of the functions up into more sensible sets - uniform random generators, normal, lognormal - and every uniform generator then creates a normal and lognormal one - i odn't want to have to create all of these manually.

Comment: @will: I still don't see why `static`. From your latest description it seems to me that you should just make a normal and a lognormal adapter that wrap the uniform generator and project the distribution accordingly. The adapters would be reusable so no duplication and zero static classes in total. I'm pretty certain you are fixated on a particular attempted solution and this prevents you from considering better ones.

Comment: @Jon I'm not rooted in the method i menthion up there. The reason for static is because all i want is a class that acts as a container for methods. I want to be able to just call the functions like library functions - the same way you can do in python - without having to initialize anything first. I then want the functions to build themselves based on just the uniform distribution i provide.

Answer (score 0):

How about composition?

```
public static class Common
{
   public static double[][] X(Func<double[][], ...> func, ...) => func(...);
}

public static class A
{
    public static double[][] X(...) => ...
    public static double[][] Y(...) => Common.X(X, ...); // use A.X
    public static double[][] Z(...) => Common.X(X, ...); // use A.X
}

public static class B
{
    public static double[][] X(...) => ...
    public static double[][] Y(...) => Common.X(X, ...); // use B.X
    public static double[][] Z(...) => Common.X(X, ...); // use B.X
}
```

`Common.X` can be a public method of `A` (or `B`). Afaik there is no way to make static member `protected`, but maybe you don't care if someone can access `Common.X`.